# How to fix multiple switch-es in javascript?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am total amateur. I am trying to use several switch-es in my javascript to apply it for very simple troubleshooting instruction (Select model>Select problem symptom>Follow repair steps). One switch is working but the other not. Both have almost the same structure. Could someone please point out where the mistake is? Basically:

```
switch (variable1) {....}
switch (variable2) {....}
switch (variable3) {....}

or
switch (variable1) 
{
..
case (n)
switch (variable2) {....}
..
}
switch (variable3) {....}
```

I started with switch in switch, it did not work. Then I created separated switch and again it is not working. M1, M2, M3 ... show up some dropdown menus. In M3, I am getting number which field from the dropdown menu was selected. Based on this (variable M3Sliczba) I want to do some actions through another switch, but this switch is not working. Have no idea why.

```
<script>
function RozpoznajModel(obj) 
{
var idModel = obj.id;
var text;
var text2;
switch(idModel) 
{
case "M1":
text = "Lista symptomów dla M1";
document.getElementById("M1_symptomy").classList.toggle("show");
break;
case "M2":
text = "Lista symptomów dla M2";
document.getElementById("M2_symptomy").classList.toggle("show");
break;
case "M3":
text = "Lista symptomów dla M3";
document.getElementById("M3_symptomy").classList.toggle("show");
document.getElementById("M3_symptomy").onchange=function()
{var 
M3Sliczba = this.value;
}
break;
case "M4":
text = "Lista symptomów dla M4";
break;
}
switch (M3Sliczba)
{
case 1:
text2 = "Make repair steps A B C D";
break;
case 2:
text2 = "Make repair steps A B C D E F G H";
break;
case 3:
text2 = "Make repair steps A B C D E F G H I J K L";
break;
}
document.write = text2;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the variable `M3Sliczba` inside an anonymous function (in your `onchange` event handler), therefore the rest of your code cannot access the variable.

Try declaring `M3Sliczba` in the outer function `RozpoznajModel` like so:

```js
function RozpoznajModel(obj) {
    var M3Sliczba;
    var idModel = obj.id;
    var text;
    var text2;
    switch (idModel) {
        case "M1":
            text = "Lista symptomów dla M1";
            document.getElementById("M1_symptomy").classList.toggle("show");
            break;
        case "M2":
            text = "Lista symptomów dla M2";
            document.getElementById("M2_symptomy").classList.toggle("show");
            break;
        case "M3":
            text = "Lista symptomów dla M3";
            document.getElementById("M3_symptomy").classList.toggle("show");
            document.getElementById("M3_symptomy").onchange = function () {
                M3Sliczba = this.value;
            }
            break;
        case "M4":
            text = "Lista symptomów dla M4";
            break;
    }
    switch (M3Sliczba) {
        case 1:
            text2 = "Make repair steps A B C D";
            break;
        case 2:
            text2 = "Make repair steps A B C D E F G H";
            break;
        case 3:
            text2 = "Make repair steps A B C D E F G H I J K L";
            break;
    }
    document.write = text2;
}
```